# How to get the value of a cell from an html table after deleting the row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that when I click on it, it dynamically generates rows in the table, it also generates a button to remove that row.
The problem I have is every time a row is generated, the value of a cell is summed in a text field, and when I remove that row I need to subtract the value from that cell to my text field.
That is why I need to get the value of that cell when it is removed.

This is my button tha generates the dynamic row in the table:

```
<input type="button" name="agregar" id="agregar" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

And this is the jQuery code for the click event of the button:

```
$("#agregar").click(function () {
        var productoId = $("#productoId").val();
        var productoDescripcion = $("#productoDescripcion").val();
        var productoPrecio = $("#productoPrecio").val();
        var productoCantidad = $("#productoCantidad").val();
        var productoIva = $("#productoIva").val();
        total = (productoPrecio * productoCantidad) - (((productoPrecio * productoCantidad) * productoIva) / 100);
        subTotal = subTotal + total;
        $("#totalAPagar").val(subTotal);
        var presupuesto = '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + productoId + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + productoDescripcion + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + productoPrecio + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + productoCantidad + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + productoIva + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + total + '</td>' +
            '<td class="eliminar-fila"><button id="eliminar" class="btn btn-danger eliminar" type="button"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></button></td>' +
            '</tr>';                

        $("#presupuestoDetalle tbody").append(presupuesto);

        $(".eliminar").click(function () {
            valor = $(this).find("td").eq(5).text();
            $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut("normal", function () {
                $(this).remove();
                subTotal = subTotal - valor;
                $("#totalAPagar").val(subTotal);
            });
        });                
    });
```

Inside this event click I have another event click on the "delete" button, which is the one in charge of removing the row. In this event click I want to get the value of the "total" cell like this:

```
valor = $(this).find("td").eq(5).text();
```

In order to be able to do this arithmetic operation: 
    subTotal = subTotal - valor;

But the field valor is in blank. How can i get the value of that cell?

Comment: Try using `text` instead of `val`. Apart from that, please do some debugging and tell us where the value gets lost, i.e. when the variables don't have the values you expect.

Comment: In the second click event is where i want to get the value of the cell 'total', but the field 'valor' doesn't have anything.

Comment: What do you mean, "*doesn't have anything*"? What value *does* it have when you log it?

Comment: I mean that it doesn't show anything when i log it in the console, but then i change .val() instead .text() and it shows 'undefined' in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a minimal verifiable sample here and found a few little points on the way:

You are assigning the click event listener for ".eliminar" potentially several times, when there are more than one lines in your table.

I changed that to a single assignment using `.on()`.

Your `valor` was determined wrongly. It needs to be something like

```
valor = $(this).closest('tr').find("td").eq(5).text();
```

```js
var subTotal=0,total=0;
$(function(){
 $("#agregar").click(function(){
   var productoId = $("#productoId").val();
   var productoDescripcion = $("#productoDescripcion").val();
   var productoPrecio = $("#productoPrecio").val();
   var productoCantidad = $("#productoCantidad").val();
   var productoIva = $("#productoIva").val();
   total = (productoPrecio * productoCantidad) - (((productoPrecio * productoCantidad) * productoIva) / 100);
   subTotal = subTotal + total;
   $("#totalAPagar").val(subTotal);
        var presupuesto = '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + productoId + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + productoDescripcion + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + productoPrecio + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + productoCantidad + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + productoIva + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + total + '</td>' +
            '<td class="eliminar-fila"><button class="btn btn-danger eliminar" type="button">eliminar</button></td>' +
            '</tr>';                
        $("#presupuestoDetalle tbody").append(presupuesto);

     
 });
 $('tbody').on("click",".eliminar",function(){
   valor = $(this).closest('tr').find("td").eq(5).text();
   $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut("normal", function () {
       $(this).remove();
       subTotal = subTotal - valor;
       $("#totalAPagar").val(subTotal);
   });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="productoId" name="productoId" value="123"/> id<br/>
<input type="text" id="productoDescripcion" name="productoDescripcion" value="producto A"/> descr.<br/>
<input type="text" id="productoPrecio" name="productoPrecio" value="10" /> precio<br/>
<input type="text" id="productoCantidad" name="productoCantidad" value="3" /> cant.<br/>
<input type="text" id="productoIva" name="productoIva" value="19" /> iva &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="totalAPagar" name="totalAPagar" value="0"><br/>
<input type="button" name="agregar" id="agregar" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-primary"/>

<table id="presupuestoDetalle">
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Descripcion</th><th>Precio</th><th>Contidad</th><th>Iva</th><th>total</th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you man, I appreciate it. You can explain to me what is  the difference in the way you use the click event in this example to the way I did it.

Comment: When you add a "delegated" event listener with `.on()` you effectively assign a *single* listener to an already existing parent element. In this case the `tbody` element of your table. The event listener looks at all incoming events of the specified type (here: "click") and fires only when the selector (here: ".eliminar") also fits, therefore it will only fire when one of the - yet to be created - buttons is clicked. Your original approach will potentially clutter your event listener with multiple assigments to a single element.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, I still do not know many things about jQuery.

Comment: "jquery-bashing" has become fashionable among young coders. But I still think the posibilities that open up by using jquery in its intended way are almost limitless and - if you do it right - you will end up with compact and easy to maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put the .parents("tr") method in the expression like this:

```
 valor = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(5).html();
```

I suppose I did not find the 'td' selector before, so first I have to go to the parent selector with .parents ('tr') and then try to find the 'td' selector, and then i put the html() method instead of the .text() method.
Now I can get the value of the cell.